# How to save uploaded image to folder in flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, werkzeug, file-storage

I save the uploaded  images with ajax and post it. I try saving the file with flask but get an error as follows. Can you help me please?

this js code

```
var image = $("#imageUpload")[0].files[0];
    var data = {
        "image": image.name,
        "image_type": image.type, 
    }
  $.ajax({
         url: "/home",
         type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
         })
```

this flask code

```
image_name = json_data[0]['image']
image_type = json_data[0]['image_type']
full_image = FileStorage(folder_path, image_name, content_type=image_type)
image_name = 'photo_' + data['uname'] + '_' + created_date + '_' + created_time + '.' + str(image_type.split('/')[1])
folder_path = 'static/img/'
image_path = folder_path + image_name
if not folder_path:
    os.mkdir(folder_path)
full_image.save(image_path)
```

this error message

> full_image.save(image_path)   File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py",
> line 3070, in save
> copyfileobj(self.stream, dst, buffer_size)   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\shutil.py", line 199, in copyfileobj
> fsrc_read = fsrc.read AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing some strings to the handler ("image" and "image_type").  You need to POST the actual data file (image) from the web page to the backend. Then use:

```
FileStorage(image, image_name, content_type=image_type)
```

This function cannot go read a file from a folder path on the client.  It needs the stream as bytes:

```
image_bytes = image.read()
```

Comment: How could I get actual data file(image)? Is "var image = $("#imageUpload")[0].files[0];" actual data ? this returns undefined

Comment: You haven't shown your web form code.  Is the file field ID `imageUpload`?  Try `console.log($("#imageUpload"))`, then  `console.log($("#imageUpload")[0])`, then `console.log($("#imageUpload")[0].files)` to see what you've got.  Once you've got it, you still have to add it to the data you are sending to the Flask backend.  Right now, you're only sending the name and the type, as strings.  if $("#imageUpload")[0].files is undefined try: `var image = $('#imageUpload').prop('files')`;